# How to change main menu appearance?

Tags: menu, multilingual

I am new to joomla, so I try to develop a multilingual site.
Everything seems to work fine except that I messed something and in my English home page the navigation menu is in a drop down menu while in the Greek one the links are side by side.
Where do I have to dig in in order to restore one way or an other for both of my home pages?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you change anything on the menu module? Are you using the same menu module for the 2 menus? Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: The page is in local pc so I can not give you access to see it. Both menu modules are identical! I opened them side by side in a separate tab of Mozilla to check for any difference but I don't see anything different.

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors. There must be something missing but it's extremely hard to tell without seeing a live preview. If you can put your site on a live host temporarily then that would make it easier for us to assist you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems that you have accidentally moved all the menu items under the "home" item as their parent. You can have a rough overview about the menu hierarchy in that menus dashboard.

If you need to be sure you can also just go into each menu items page and check for the "parent item" and make sure its "Menu item root" for all the items those you want side by side.

[image: Joomla 3, Menu messed up, all items under 1 menu item dropdown.]